# Setting tab size/ space size as default in VSCode

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm currently using VSCode and I have this problem. I want to set the space size equals to 1 and tab size equals to 2 as default for every project. But it still set back as spaces: 4 for every project.
And as I set the spaces = 2, and run Beautify file. Everything looks good with space = 2. Then I hit save it format my file to indent size 4. How do I set it as default equal to 2 guys?

[image: Still Spaces: 4]

even I change in User settings

[image]

Comment: Do you have an option which convert tabs to spaces?

Answer (score 15):

By default VSCode try to detect indent option for a file. So set editor.detectIndentation to false

```
// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces` will be detected based on the file contents.
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

EditorConfig is a handy standard for establishing project wide formatting options: http://editorconfig.org.

There's a VSCode extension supporting it: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it works well. And if you switch editors, you still can keep your formatting standard by getting each editor's plug-in for EditorConfig.

Comment: How do we config the EditorConfig settings in VSCode?

Comment: Just install the extension and create its config file as described here: http://editorconfig.org.